# mypy does not recognize a method of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, command-pattern

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List


class AirConditioner:
    """Class that represents an air conditioner"""

    def __init__(self, identify: str, state: bool, temperature: int):
        self.identify = identify
        self._state = state
        self._temperature = temperature

    def turn_on(self) -> None:
        self._state = True

    def turn_off(self) -> None:
        self._state = False

    def set_temperature(self, temperature: int) -> None:
        self._temperature = temperature

    def get_state(self) -> bool:
        return self._state

    def get_temperature(self) -> int:
        return self._temperature


class ICommand(ABC):
    """Interface that represents a command"""

    @abstractmethod
    def execute(self) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def undo(self) -> None:
        pass


class TurnOnAirConditioner(ICommand):
    """Class that represents a command to turn on an air conditioner"""

    def __init__(self, air_conditioner: AirConditioner):
        self._air_conditioner = air_conditioner

    def execute(self) -> None:
        self._air_conditioner.turn_on()

    def undo(self) -> None:
        self._air_conditioner.turn_off()


class ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner(ICommand):
    """Class that represents a command to change the temperature of an air conditioner"""

    def __init__(self, air_conditioner: AirConditioner):
        self._air_conditioner = air_conditioner
        self._temperature = air_conditioner.get_temperature()
        self._temperature_anterior = self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, temperature: int) -> None:
        self._temperature_anterior = self._temperature
        self._temperature = temperature

    def execute(self) -> None:
        self._air_conditioner.set_temperature(self._temperature)

    def undo(self) -> None:
        self._air_conditioner.set_temperature(self._temperature_anterior)


class Aplicativo:
    """Class that represents an application that uses the command pattern to control an air conditioner"""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._comandos: List[ICommand] = []

    def set_comando(self, comando_app: ICommand) -> int:
        self._comandos.append(comando_app)
        return len(self._comandos) - 1

    def get_command(self, comando_id: int) -> ICommand:
        return self._comandos[comando_id]

    def pressing_button(self, comando_id: int) -> None:
        self._comandos[comando_id].execute()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplicativo()

    my_air_conditioner = AirConditioner("Air Conditioner", False, 26)

    change_temperature_air = ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner(my_air_conditioner)
    turn_on_ar = TurnOnAirConditioner(my_air_conditioner)

    ID_TURN_AIR_ON = app.set_comando(turn_on_ar)
    ID_CHANGE_AIR_TEMPERATURE = app.set_comando(change_temperature_air)

    app.pressing_button(ID_TURN_AIR_ON)
    comando = app.get_command(ID_CHANGE_AIR_TEMPERATURE)
    comando.set_temperature(25)
```

When I run the code above, mypy brings me the following alert:

error: "ICommand" has no attribute "set_temperature" [attr-defined]

How do I do it when I need to call a method, but not every class that implements the ICommand interface has this method?

I tried to comment lines with #type ignore, but I would like to know a better way to handle this problem

Comment: As a side note, those `get_x`/`set_x` methods are usually an anti-pattern. Any reason you're not using properties?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I'm aware of that.
This is an example I reproduced just to understand the problem with mypy, not worrying about styling etc.

Comment: The problem is that nothing in your code promises that `ID_CHANGE_AIR_TEMPERATURE` will map to something that has a method `set_temperature`. You probably need to enforce this through `cast`, generics or perhaps a type-guard. Alternatively change your `ICommand` interface, to include a generic way to pass data (`Any`, `Dict[str, Any]`, etc.)

Comment: Better yet, don't use generic stuff where it doesn't belong.

Comment: anyone else...?

Comment: In the command pattern, anyway, the whole point is that the only way to interact with a Command is through `execute`, that does the decoupling. Also probably important to note, you wouldn't really use the command pattern in Python, you would probably just use a callback (note, in that sense, the callback being called is the only way to interact with it! you *execute* the callback, usually with some prescribed arguments)

Comment: So what you *should* do here if you want to use that method is use type-narrowing, something like `if isinstance(comando, ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner): comando.set_temperature(25)` then probably `else: raise RuntimeError(...)`. You can also just use `assert isinstance(comando, ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner)`

Comment: `execute` and `undo`, in your case, but the point is you only interact with it through the `ICommand` interface

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for type-narrowing solution (upvoted). I'll be reading more about it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following mypy guidelines:

> In cases where your code is too magical for mypy to understand, you
> can make a variable or parameter dynamically typed by explicitly
> giving it the type Any

source: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dynamic_typing.html

The best way to solve this problem is change `get_command` method, in `Aplicativo` class to:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import List, Any
    
    ...

class Aplicativo:
        """Class that represents an application that uses the command pattern to control an air conditioner"""
    
        ...

        def get_command(self, comando_id: int) -> Any:
            return self._comandos[comando_id]

        ...
```

Solving the issue with mypy

Comment: This *ignores* the issue. It doesn't solve it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think if I used #type ignore I would actually be ignoring the problem. For dynamically typed code cases, Any becomes a viable path. Another would be the one proposed by colleague Jeppe

Comment: `Any` is essentially "don't type this function *anywhere it's used*. It *is* ignoring the issue.  You should use type narrowing (explicit type checking). In Java, for example, you would use a downcast, which does the explicit type checking

Answer (score 1):

Consider these two lines:

```
comando = app.get_command(ID_CHANGE_AIR_TEMPERATURE)
comando.set_temperature(25)
```

Even if we ignore the fact that you call your variable `ID_CHANGE_AIR_TEMPERATURE`, it still implies that you know `comando` is of type `ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner` from how you use it (you call `.set_temperature(25)` on it).

One solution would then be to `cast` from `ICommand` to `ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner`:

```
from typing import cast
comando = cast(ChangeTemperatureAirConditioner, app.get_command(ID_CHANGE_AIR_TEMPERATURE))
```

Comment: In fact, I find it curious that we need to add an extra line to inform the type-checker that something is of some type, seems like overkill.

Despite believing that in these cases the use of Any is the most viable, I learned that there is this possibility of casting.

Thanks for the answer (I upvoted it)

Comment: @TóRugain I would personally much rather use casting than `Any`. The underlying problem is the inconsistency in your design - that `set_temperature` is not common to all `ICommand` implementors. Neither `cast` nor `Any` solves the underlying problem, that you may in fact have an `ICommand` which doesn't have `set_temperature` and then you will get a run-time exception. But `cast` at least allows you to have type-safety, which is the goal of mypy.